# php - "Division by zero" with euler constant

Tags: php, runtime-error, divide-by-zero

I have this simple function:

[image]

And this is the code I wrote to implement it:

```
public function SimpleEquation($top, $bottom){
    $result = (-1/(1 + M_E^(2*M_E - 2*($top/$bottom)))) + 1.032; //this is line 123.
    $result = round($result, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    return $result;
}
```

But when I execute it, it gives the error:

> ErrorException in MyFile.php line 123: Division by zero

Basically I thought that there was something wrong with the incoming input, this is why I tried the equation with constant values that cause problem to the function instead of variables:

```
$result = (-1/(1 + M_E^(2*M_E - 2*(5.05/5.78)))) + 1.032;
echo "Result: ".$result."<br>";
```

This causes the same division by zero error as well. I tried rewriting the equation more than 4 times from scratch, and it works quite well with most of the values. I also tried to use a simple constant like `$eulerConstant = 2.718` just in case there was an overflow or something with the system but it still gave me the same result.

I would be really happy with a help about why this does not work.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @cale_b that's given by PHP as `2.718281828459`

Comment: `(1 + M_E^(2*M_E - 2*(5.05/5.78)))` evaluates as zero.

Comment: I also tried another variable that is created by me called `$eulerConstant = 2.718` and it still did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exponentiation is done with the [`pow`](http://php.net/pow) function, not the [`^` bitwise-XOR operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).